# Keep UITableViewCell accessory on top

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessorytype

I have a UITableViewCell with a accessorytype detail indicator. When I resize the cell, the cells accessory centers itself horizontally. How can I make it stay on top, and not center itself?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cellID" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

I'd prefer doing it in the storyboard if possible, if not, I'm happy to hear how to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake, Actually you can't do any change in default accessoryView of tableView, You need to create a custom accessoryView for your cell. Just ignore the accessory type because it will not longer matters once you create your own accessoryView.

try this code in CellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if(!cell.accessoryView)
{
   UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //add target if necessary
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    //apply customisations 
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't work. I do have a custom cell, so maybe that's the reason?